# How to set multiple sell/buy orders in Pine Script V5 Bollinger Bands Code?

Tags: signals, pine-script

image

[image: 1]

I have a simple Bollinger Bands code here that has been working so far. However, the problem is that only a sell limit order is set, followed by a buy limit order, even when multiple sell signals (or buy signals) occur in succession. How can I solve this problem? I have attached an image.

```
strategy("Bollinger Bands Strategy V6", overlay=true)
source = close[0]
length = input.int(20, minval=1)
mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50)
basis = ta.sma(source, length)
dev = mult * ta.stdev(source, length)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev

smaHIGH = ta.sma(high[0], 1)
plot(smaHIGH, offset=0, color = color.rgb(206, 59, 232))

smaLOW = ta.sma(low[0], 1)
plot(smaLOW, offset=0, color = color.rgb(232, 145, 175))



plot(upper)
plot(lower)

if smaHIGH >= lower
    strategy.entry("Buy L", strategy.long, limit = lower, oca_name="BollingerBands", oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel, comment="Buy L")

if smaLOW <= upper
    strategy.entry("Sell L", strategy.short, limit = upper, oca_name="BollingerBands", oca_type=strategy.oca.cancel, comment="Sell L")
```

Comment: @Gu57avo71, same problem with pyramid.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple entries, you must enable the [pyramid](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/pyramiding.asp)

You can do it [manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lf2i7.png), or from [strategy](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy)